# Normplot colormap in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, color-mapping

I have a set of vectors in the shape of a n by m matrix from which I would like to calculate m normplots superimposed. This is easy:

```
c=rand(100,10);
figure
normplot(c)
```

The normplot automatically colors each column of data, but I would like to control how they are colored. Specifically I need to make them greyscale. The first set of data (column 1) should be white (or close to white) and the last one black.

Comment: As I have no Matlab installed I can only give a link to the corresponding help page from MathWorks: [Defining Your Own ColorOrder
](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/creating_plots/defining-the-color-of-lines-for-plotting.html?searchHighlight=ColorOrder#brdjjco-1)

Answer (score 3):

By obtaining the handles to the plotted lines you could something like this:

```
close all;
n = 100;
m = 10;
doc=rand(n,m);
figure;

% obtain the handle h to the dotted lines
h = normplot(doc);

% define colormap
g = colormap('gray');

for i = 1:m
    %set(h([1 11 21]),'color','r') % to set color to red
    %set(h([1 11 21]),'marker','o') % to change marker

    % mapping into greyscale color map (g has size 64x3)
    set(h([i i+m i+2*m]),'color',g(round(i * size(g,1)/m),:));
end
```

[image]